# Should we relax the tag creation rules for this site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

SFF won't reuse that many tags as other Stack Exchange sites. Each time someone wants to talk about a novel no one has talked about yet, it'll require the creation of a new tag. When that's the case, the new user will end up using [useless tags](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/2159/revisions) that [should be blacklisted anyhow](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/).

So, should we let new users create new tags, or would that go horribly wrong?

Answer (score 10):

The reputation requirement for creating a tag is only 300 (150 as long as the site is in beta), and retagging other people's posts comes at 500 (200 in beta, and everyone can suggest an edit now). We already have 114 users who can create tags and add them to a question without supervision. On the other beta sites where I've participated, the community has proved effective at creating tags as required.

I'm not even convinced we'll end up having that many low-use tags compared to other sites. For example sites like [Super User](https://superuser.com/) and [Unix and Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) have a lot of tags for applications that very few people ask about.

Having a minimum participation requirement before creating tags is a good thing for consistency. If the tag creation requirements are too low we increase the risk of author name spelling variants coming up and the like.

TL,DR: I think the normal tag creation rules are fine.

Answer (score 1):

> Each time someone wants to talk about a novel no one has talked about yet, it'll require the creation of a new tag

I absolutely *do not* think you want to create one tag for every novel ever written.

That is ridiculous!

Popular series like Lord of the Rings, perhaps. Genres, certainly. But a tag for every novel? No way. Absolutely not.

Comment: Why not? ("That is ridiculous" is barely an argument)

Comment: @tim true. Here's specifics: it creates a lot of problems with the tagging system. Any tag should be able to pass the "more than 2 questions will exist in a 6 month period" test, and the "will another human being actually subscribe to this tag?" test. And that's just a start! Neither is likely in the case where every novel ever written has its own tag.