# General tagging practices

Tags: discussion, tags

What are our general tagging practices?

A few current practices are:

- Questions about a specific tv show, universe or well-known work: [dune](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dune), [battlestar-galactica](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/battlestar-galactica)
- Questions about a specific author, or an author's lesser-known work: use the author's full name, e.g. [isaac-asimov](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isaac-asimov)
- Story identification questions: [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification)
- Questions covering a specific subgenre: [alternate-history](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alternate-history), [hard-scifi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-scifi), …
- Questions covering a specific theme: [aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens), [weapon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/weapon), …
- Questions about a specific medium or format: [movies](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movies), [novels](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novels), … *These are [deprecated](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/should-we-do-away-with-the-media-tags-books-novel-tv-movies-etc)*

What other practices are recommended?

Comment: About medium tags: for tags that you deem deprecated, they're still heavily used, though inconsistently. Is that a case where people are misusing the tags or am I understanding it wrong?

Comment: @Borror0: I call them deprecated because most of the people who replied to [your question](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/293/should-we-do-away-with-the-media-tags-books-novel-tv-movies-etc) were against them. They're still there because no one has removed them. I'm willing to mass-delete them (mods have a tool for that), but I'd rather see the response here first.

Comment: @gilles the two answers with the most votes are "it depends" and "some might sometimes be useful".  That doesn't seem against?

Comment: @Tony: against having them systematically. You're right that this doesn't justify removing the tags altogether.

Comment: Perhaps http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/421/naming-convention-for-tags could be merged with this question?

Comment: @Tony: I lean towards keeping these questions separate: what tags to use here, how to choose the names there.

Answer (score 6):

Here are some guidelines for choosing tags for a question about a specific work:

- For books and short stories, use the [author's name](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/421/naming-convention-for-tags) as a tag (e.g. [isaac-asimov](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/isaac-asimov)). For media franchises, use the franchise name as a tag, e.g. [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek).

  - [Do not use more precise tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/408/should-we-relax-the-tag-creation-rules-for-this-site/410#410) such as titles of specific books or specific seasons of TV series, except for *extremely* popular works such as [lord-of-the-rings](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lord-of-the-rings).
- If at all applicable, strive to use [tags for plot or setting elements](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/514/connecting-tags), e.g. [aliens](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aliens), [good-against-evil](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/good-against-evil).
- Consider using subgenre tags if applicable, e.g. [hard-sci-fi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hard-sci-fi), [urban-fantasy](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/urban-fantasy).
- Do not use [media tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/should-we-do-away-with-the-media-tags-books-novel-tv-movies-etc) such as [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) or [short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories) just to indicate that a particular work is in a particular format. Use these tags only when the medium is intrinsically relevant to your question, e.g. [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie) to indicate a movie adaptation of a book.