# Please, remove "yoda", "darth-vader" and "obi-wan-kenobi" tags

Tags: feature-request, tags

We've already disapproved character tags: [Star-Wars character tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/843/star-wars-character-tags)

Also, based on this, @Null recently removed [r2-d2](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/r2-d2) tag from one of my questions. It means it's in action.

Please, remove [yoda](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yoda), [darth-vader](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/darth-vader) and [obi-wan-kenobi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obi-wan-kenobi) tags.

Comment: It's going to take time to make sure we don't spam the front page.

Answer (score 7):

We are *slowly* cleaning up character tags on a tag-by-tag basis.

Not all character tags are being removed; rather, the consensus based on recent meta discussions is that character tags should stick around if they identify some significant subset of question that a person might be an "expert" in. In other words, it's *feasible* that someone could know a whole lot about Darth Vader, but not really be interested in the rest of Star Wars. OTOH, it's less likely that someone would *only* want to answer questions about R2-D2 -- those questions will probably be answered by people who are general Star Wars experts.

It is ultimately a subjective decision, but we've started by getting rid of the "easy" cases: tags with the smallest number of tagged questions, tags that seem to be redundant on every question they're used in, etc. And, it needs to be done slowly and carefull, or we'll end up flooding the front page with old questions.

If [yoda](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/yoda), [darth-vader](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/darth-vader), and [obi-wan-kenobi](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/obi-wan-kenobi) fit the bill for deletion, someone will get around to them eventually.

Comment: Given that there are entire solo books and comics dedicated to vader and obi-wan, I'm inclined to let those ones live. I think the amount of dedicated material should play into our culling, I'm just not sure exactly where to draw the line.

Comment: I think you've given a good rule of thumb there: it someone has their own dedicated source material, that means it's possible (if unlikely) someone is an expert *only* on Vader, so that would be a legit tag. Maybe we also edit something into the tag summary *suggesting* people use it mostly for "solo works"? dunno if that would help or not...

Comment: If not enough people are using the tags, they should be removed.  *Star Wars* is popular enough that there should already be abundant use of each of these tags if they're useful enough to keep.  A dozen [tag:yoda] questions means we can probably get rid of that tag.