# How should this question be tagged?

Tags: discussion, tags, specific-question, retagging

[Who/what made the noises on Miss Lucy's window?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/35939/who-what-made-the-noises-on-miss-lucys-window)

Now it's tagged [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books)+[dracula](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dracula).

I was thinking that [bram-stokers-dracula](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bram-stokers-dracula) would be better as a tag, but not entirely sure so won't retag without people agreeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Leave it alone, or add an author tag.

*Bram Stoker's Dracula* is actually the title of [the 1992 film](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bram_Stoker's_Dracula) by Coppola. [The novel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dracula)'s title is just *Dracula,* and should be tagged as such; the [book](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/book) tag should give enough extra context.

If more definition is necessary then a [bram-stoker](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bram-stoker) tag would be useful, but the tag wiki should clarify that it's about [the real-life author](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bram_Stoker).

I'm basing this on [this meta answer](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/general-tagging-practices) about tagging practices, which addresses how to tag a specific work within a franchise/series. Basically, it advises to specify author's name and franchise tag instead of specific titles/seasons.

Answer (score 0):

There are dozens of books with Dracula in them, Fred Saberhagen (author of the Berserker series) wrote quite a few himself. (In them, Dracula was the anti-hero.)

You should leave it tagged both "book" and "dracula", but it probably should have a third tag. And as BESW suggests, we do need to avoid ambiguity with the 1992 film. Not sure how to do that. Perhaps include the year in the tag name for the film, as wikipedia does for articles.

Comment: Do we *need* to distinguish one novel/film from another in the tags? That could lead to a proliferation of single-use tags (usually bad), and would probably impede more generic searches (which would probably be more common). An author/director tag might see more use?

Comment: @BESW The whole point of tags is to distinguish. If we didn't want to do that, we could just tag it "vampire" and make people search through an ocean of Twilight questions to find content they are interested in.

Comment: I just added a bit on my answer linking to a general tagging policy that advises against more precise tags in this kind of situation; [tag:book] and [tag:bram-stoker] should be sufficient for a future user to narrow their search.