# Can we add a way to allow tags to be marked as dependent upon other tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

I know [this has been discussed before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2781/166646), however, the discussion seems to be primarily focused on how it would pertain to Stack Overflow, with the apparent conclusion being that this is a sign of things being tagged incorrectly, rather than a need for something useful.

On other Stack Exchange sites, though, there are cases where this would most definitely *not* indicate incorrect tag usage.

For example, on [scifi.se](http://scifi.stackexchange.com), there are many tags used to refine specific franchise tags.  Some examples:

- [`harry-potter`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) has many sub-tags such as [`aldus-dumbledore`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/aldus-dumbledore) (48 questions), [`hogwarts`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hogwarts) (55 questions), [`voldemort`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voldemort) (149 questions), etc., as well as tags specific to individual books/movies.
- [`star-wars`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars) also has sub-tags including specific movie titles as well as [`the-clone-wars`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-clone-wars), character tags ([`darth-vader`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/darth-vader): 45 questions; [`luke-skywalker`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/luke-skywalker): 27 questions, etc.), and franchise-specific tags like [`the-force`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-force) (46 questions), [`jedi`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jedi) (66 questions) and [`sith`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sith) (34 questions)
- Author specific tags are frequently forgotten.  An excellent example is [`george-r-r-martin`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/george-r-r-martin), which should be used for every question related to one of his works (including *Game of Thrones* TV show, *A Song of Ice and Fire* books, and various short stories and novels unrelated to those titles).  However, we have 181 questions tagged with the author, but 372 tagged with [`a-song-of-ice-and-fire`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire) and 398 tagged [`game-of-thrones`](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones).

I have seen similar issues on other sites, such as [Arqade.com](http://gaming.stackexchange.com), which has some instances of class-specific questions that fall under [more general title tags](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/diablo-3).

I know we have several users who make an effort to fix these when they can, but it is a difficult task, particularly since these examples are all very popular titles, especially for new users who aren't very familiar with the tagging system.

It would be really helpful if we could have the larger franchise and author tags listed as mandatory, or even implied, whenever the tags that are clearly always sub-tags are used.

It would be up to the individual community to very carefully evaluate which, *if any* tags would be set up this way, but it would make cleanup for those communities that have clearly-defined subset tags much easier.

Comment: I think you're incorrect on the `george-r-r-martin` thing, but the rest of the tag hierarchy would be nice to have.  If I tag something `star-trek-tng`, it should also be tagged `star-trek`.  This is similar to how on SO, tagging something with `some C++ library` should probably have `C++` on there too.

Comment: @Keen Yeah, I've rethought my position on the author tags... and most of the others, as well.

Answer (score 3):

Why does a question tagged `game-of-thrones` *have* to be tagged with `george-r-r-martin`? Surely this relies on the author of the question knowing that Mr Martin is the author of the books upon which the TV series is based. Something you can't assume. But [from the meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/general-tagging-practices/548#548) where you define this rule it states:

> Do not use more precise tags

So, this would imply that it's not that you need tags to be linked, just that people are using inappropriate "precise" tags when the more general ones are what they should be using.

The important thing to remember is that you should be able to apply a single tag to a question and have it make sense.

Users can favourite multiple tags and include multiple tags in searches so there are tools to ensure that you don't miss a question.

If anything it sounds like your `george-r-r-martin` and `star-wars` type tags are redundant and you should be using the more specific tags for a given character or film/book.

Comment: @Beofett Then maybe your question should be posted on meta.scifi - I don't see how this would fit for other sites.

Comment: @bluefeet I thought all feature requests were to go through this meta?  I'll take a look at other graduated SE sites and see if I can find any others, but this meta is no longer just the trilogy, as I understand it.

Comment: @Beofett If you think a feature should be implemented on all sites, then yes, post to MSE.  If not site wide, then you can post a feature request on Meta specific to that site. This seems really targeted to SciFi, I don't see how something like this would work on SO.

Comment: @Beofett - if your feature request is site specific it should be asked on you site's meta.

Comment: @ChrisF I guess I'm not clear if this *should* be site-specific.  It certainly seemed as if the (rather old) discussion I linked indicated there was popular support for this as a feature for other sites, including SO, so I thought it might merit wider discussion.

Comment: It seems to me that your tag wiki descriptions could include a list of related tags. See, for example: http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/notifications/info

Comment: @Beofett Tag hierarchies are indeed popular, but have been rejected time and time again.

Comment: @ChrisF Regarding your edit: you have missed the rest of the meta discussion that you quoted, which is extremely relevant here: `except for extremely popular works`.  Certainly Star Wars and Harry Potter qualify as "extremely popular works" on our site, especially since they both have more questions than the example Lord of the Rings specifically called out as a good situation for using more precise tags.

Comment: On a personal level I find it most frustrating that despite that I've marked [tag:Game-of-Thrones] to be hidden, only to immediately come upon spoilers for the current season because the questioner has seen fit to tag it with [tag:ASOIAF] and [tag:Stannis-Baratheon]