# Why are we keeping a [kill-count]?

Tags: discussion, tags

Do we really need [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count)?  Tag scoring checklist stolen from [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/tag-wars-episode-i-harry-potter-and-the-tag-cleanup):

1. Does it make sense to be an "expert* in [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count)"?
   **No,** because questions with this tag could belong to any fictional universe and you cannot possibly know them all.  -1
2. Does it make sense for a question to be tagged only with [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count)"?
   **No,** it would need to have a franchise or work tag at a minimum.  -1
3. Does [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count) have a single, universally-unambiguous meaning?
   **Yes.** +2
4. Is [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count) likely to be used correctly just based on it's name?
   **Yes.** +2
5. Are there "enough" (> 15) but not "too many" (> 10% site-wide) questions that qualify for [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count)?
   **Maybe,** there are nine now and I could imagine that a few more might exist but not have the tag (or be asked in the future).  >10% site-wide is *never* going to happen.  +1
6. Are people like to use [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count) to find questions to answer?
   **Maybe,** some people might like doing the kind of math and trivia this involves.  +1
7. Are there likely some users (be objective!) who will favorite or ignore [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count)?
   **Maybe,** but I doubt it.  +1
8. Could [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count) be reasonably used to feed questions to a specialized chat room?
   **I can't imagine why you'd want to do that**, and the question frequency is low enough that there really wouldn't be much point.  -1
9. Can [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count) be used to search for questions (for any reason) in a way that keyword searching cannot accomplish?
   **No.**  These questions all involve one of the words "died," "killed," and "body."  You can just keyword search on terms such as those.  -1

**Final score:** +3, which is well into the "terrible" zone:

> Very roughly speaking, tags that score > 12 are "good" tags, tags that score < 8 are "terrible" tags, others are likely good but may need some clarification/renaming/etc.

I don't have the rep to mass edit these nine questions without going through approval, but I would suggest that someone with the rep do so, since this looks like a fairly open-and-shut case to me.

Comment: I'd score it 7, but I also don't see a reason to remove unique tags that aren't redundant.  If this was an answer, the TL;DR would be "Meh, why get rid of it?  It isn't actively harmful."

Comment: @WadCheber very few bad tags are 'harmful'. It's the aggregate collection of useless tags that is considered harmful. Care to explain your +7 score in an answer?

Comment: @AncientSwordRage Is it useless?  I don't think so.  Having a "Darth Vader" AND an "Anakin Skywalker" is useless, but this is a tag that describes a specific concept that isn't completely found in any other tag.   I really don't care enough to post an answer.

Comment: These questions need it adding - http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/79703/how-many-people-has-wolverine-killed-in-the-x-men-movies, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117475/how-many-times-is-jar-jar-killed-in-lego-star-wars,

Comment: And these; http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/83367/in-star-trek-into-darkness-how-many-died-from-the-crash-in-san-francisco, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/99297/total-droid-death-in-the-clone-wars, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/120520/how-many-people-died-during-grindelwalds-reign/121478#121478, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/94430/which-earth-616-marvel-character-has-the-highest-kill-count, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/58435/average-deaths-per-episode

Comment: Community [consensus](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/9215/31394) is that the tag scoring system you've used here isn't really useful. A shorter list of criteria can be found on [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/278659), if you really want a list.

Comment: Can't be an expert in it??? Tell that to [Dead Meat](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC2IYWWifoIht9T47z1Z5lJw) and [Kill Counts](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCS3rvGI9KoQzvRa9i0ZIS7A)

Answer (score 4):

Your criteria (which were originally proposed [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/tag-wars-episode-i-harry-potter-and-the-tag-cleanup) having been copied over from Chemistry SE) were popular here on SFF meta for a while, but gradually decreased in popularity, until eventually [the question was posed](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9215/31394) of whether they were actually useful and met with a resounding **no**.

If you really want a tag-scoring system, there's a relatively short and easy one [on main meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/278659):

> 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied?
> 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?
> 3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?
> 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

In this case, [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count) would get the answer **yes** for all four of these questions. Another important question is "**does the tag aid in searchability?**", to which again the answer is yes, since it's hard to search for questions about kill counts using just the search facility: the question "how many X did Y kill in Z?" can come in many different forms, and if one's interested in finding all such questions, having a special tag for them would be very useful.

Admittedly, if someone was proposing the *creation* of this tag, I would probably be against it. But now that it exists, and seems to satisfy a bunch of sensible criteria for tags, it's certainly not worth the trouble of burninating it. To quote [the top-voted answer here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9216/31394):

> Tagging was never meant to be this much of a pain in the ass to make decisions on. Unless a tag is atrociously bad or almost unused, it may as well stay.
>
> [...]
>
> Any tag we prevent from being made or burninate actually destroys our ability to track the actual usage of tags, to develop policies based around what our users naturally feel is an effective way to tag questions.

### TL;DR: leave it alone.

Answer (score 1):

**Leave [kill-count](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/kill-count) alone.**

---

For my money, the most important of the criteria you've mentioned is #6, **are people likely to use it to search for questions about kill-counts**? Since the answer is a very firm "yes", that means that it's worthwhile keeping it.

---

**I think we need a new criteria for retagging.**

1) Is it possible that removing this tag could harm, rather than improve the ability of users to find questions that interest them? **Y/N**

2) Will retagging a bunch of these questions bugger up the front page for a day? **Y/Y**

If the answer to either of these questions is yes, **leave the tag alone.**

Comment: To be fair, adding this tag to the other questions to which it applies (as listed in your comments) would bugger up the front page just as much as removing it from the questions it's currently on.

Comment: @randal'thor - Which is why you should only do them a couple at a time on a normal day.

Comment: Far less eloquent than Mr 'Thor, but fully reflecting my personal opinion, especially on #1. OP's evaluation of the original criteria was also WAY off base, by the way -  #9 is "2", not "-1", for reasons I stated elsewhere on Meta.