# Should there be an "H. Beam Piper" tag?

Tags: discussion

I would browse this tag. However, there are only [18 hits on "Beam Piper"](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%22beam%20piper%22) on the site, and many refer to story identification *answers* (i.e., not people who know they're looking for H. Beam Piper).  What are the general grounds for an acceptable level of notability to warrant a tag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A cursory glance at the site's 18 uses of "Beam Piper" reveals precisely zero questions about the works of H. (Horace? Herbert? Henry?) Beam Piper. As you've indicated, the majority of mentions are story-ID questions (where re-tagging with the author's name would be inappropriate) and "first example of" questions.

Noting that we [don't usually create an author tags unless there's a good reason to do so](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7923/what-is-the-correct-usage-of-individual-works-tags-vs-author-tags-vs-franchise) (for example, someone asking a question *about that author*), we certainly won't create a tag until someone asks a question about their works since [that tag will just get roomba'd](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19753/how-can-we-get-rid-of-misspelled-and-unused-or-zombie-tags) if there aren't any relevant questions attached to it.

> *"Tags not associated with any question are automatically destroyed at 03:00 UTC every day."*

Comment: On the other hand, if you ask a question about Piper (for example, "***What did the H stand for in H. Beam Piper***") then an author tag would almost certainly be created.

Comment: that would feel like cheating since I could easily find the answer (or, non-answer) in the second paragraph of his Wikipedia entry.  But maybe I will ask a more substantive question sometime.

Comment: @BenBolker - The wikipedia article seems to suggest that he almost wilfully went by a variety of names. What it doesn't answer is what his actual name was.

Comment: Note that an exception to the general policy of using author tags only for questions about the author themselves can be [questions about short stories](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10230/31394), where it's not worth giving the story its own tag. (cc @BenBolker)