# Should we have a Malcolm-Reynolds tag?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

30 questions contain "Mal" and 16 of them are about the one from Firefly.  I know this isn't that many, but [this post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7871/tag-wars-episode-i-harry-potter-and-the-tag-cleanup) seems to think it is enough.  Besides, we do have tags with less questions.  Scoring [malcolm-reynolds](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malcolm-reynolds) using the system from the above post, we get 12 (1, -1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2) which is enough to make it a tag.  (You may not agree with my rankings, just tell me and I'll look at 'em.)  Should we have [malcolm-reynolds](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malcolm-reynolds) as a tag?

Comment: Related: http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/6839/when-should-character-tags-be-created-recreated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Meh.

Among the [15 questions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfirefly%5D+mal+is%3Aq) which mention "Mal" and are tagged [firefly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefly), [at](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67475/why-doesnt-captain-mal-let-saffron-answer-at-the-end-of-our-mrs-reynolds) [most](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/143288/why-does-mal-change-his-mind) [six](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50760/why-does-mal-abandon-the-tams-in-safe) [are](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146150/did-mal-intentionally-leave-jayne-with-the-tams-in-ariel) [actually](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/11139/is-there-any-evidence-that-mal-thought-more-of-inara-than-anyone-else-on-his-cre) [*about*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/87403/why-was-mal-able-to-shrug-off-apparently-lethal-blows-from-the-operative) Malcolm Reynolds, rather than simply mentioning him. So the proposed [malcolm-reynolds](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/malcolm-reynolds) tag wouldn't even pass [Shog9's test](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7832/31394) for character tags. (And it's worth noting that that advice hasn't really been followed in practice, in terms of *creating* tags; the way the community has interpreted it seems to be just that a character tag isn't worth *destroying* if there are at least 10 questions with it. Otherwise we'd have a [rand-althor](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rand-althor) tag by now, as well as a lot more Harry Potter character tags than we do).

General rules aside, it just doesn't seem worth it IMO. We have 86 [firefly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefly) questions currently, most of which are general questions about the universe or the plot rather than about specific characters. Plus, since Mal is the main character of the show, I doubt anyone would be interested in following/ignoring a tag about him specifically if they don't already follow/ignore the [firefly](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/firefly) tag.

(By the way, the tag checklist you mentioned has [since been rejected](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9215/31394) by the community.)

Comment: Sound reasoning; I agree with everything here.