# Do we have any tag creation guidelines?

Tags: discussion, tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [General tagging practices](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/412/general-tagging-practices)

I asked a [question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/in-timeline-does-a-time-traveller-truly-die-during-transit) that required the creation of a tag(s). I created a tag for the author and the novel. The novel tag was removed from it. I've found a [meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/408/should-we-relax-the-tag-creation-rules-for-this-site) suggesting we don't create a tag for every novel. I also didn't see anything in the FAQ pertaining to this.

Do we have any rules or guidelines down for tag creation?

Comment: [Yes, we do](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/412/general-tagging-practices), but I admit they aren't particularly easy to find.

Comment: Curse my search terms! I never stuck "general" or "practices" with "tag". Thanks for the link! Can we get that linked in the FAQ? Might make things easier for other noobs in the future.

Comment: I've added [a few explanations of common cases](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/412/general-tagging-practices/548#548). I tried giving the question more visibility but ran into a [technical snag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92194/149076). I'm aware that our FAQ organization is far from perfect, suggestions are welcome.