# Rename the story-identification tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, story-identification

All identification questions are currently lumped under one tag: [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification).

Would it make more sense to separate out the different media and have `identify-this-story`, `identify-this-movie`, `identify-this-series`? I can see two advantage to this format:

- It allows people to subscribe to only the media that they like. For example a movie buff who doesn't read much could subscribe to `identify-this-movie` and not bother with `identify-this-story`. You could still subscribe to all of them by subscribing to `identify-this-*` (yes, although this isn't evident from the UI, you can use wildcards in favorite tags).
- There wouldn't be any call for [media tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/should-we-do-away-with-the-media-tags-books-novel-tv-movies-etc) on story identification questions then.

<sub>Yes, I'm guilty of creating the `story-identification` tag, in an imitation of [YASID](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/YASID) on [rasfw](http://acronyms.thefreedictionary.com/rasfw). But I now suspect it was a mistake.</sub>

Comment: oh god, not the "identify this thing I can't remember" plague here, too: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1455/what-is-the-point-of-help-me-remember-this-game-questions

Comment: @Jeff whether or not to allow these questions was discussed (at length) a long time (in beta terms) back.  This question is only about the tags used, not whether they are on-topic, which they definitely are.  There was much discussion over your earlier comments, with the conclusion (eventually) that they were not an outright ban.

Comment: The wildcard-in-tag argument is compelling, although I don't know whether it is reasonable to think that people would discover that they could do that.  Is identify-this-story meant for all printed material? If so, I don't think it adequately excludes TV/film (those are stories, too).

Comment: What kind of series is identify-this-series for? Novels, short stories, movies, radio programs?

Answer (score 3):

My point - it's a bad idea.

From one of my questions, I mistook a book with a movie, there also was an episode where I've been thinking there's an actual filmed version of another story.

Sci-fi and fantasy are .. fantasy, which hooks us with dream world. Lucid dreaming together with poor memory can be disastrous - I've seen here a question, where a "short" (15+ min) Michael Jackson lengthy clip was initially thought to be a full-length movie.

"media" tags? How far you expect to go with it? **it-was-on-page-313**, **omfg-im-sure-its-a-final-battle-scene-and-not-the-intro**?

Comment: +1, agreed.  I'd also add: what if someone hasn't seen a movie but is able to make the identification from it's novelization?  And where do we stop?  Comics?  Baseball cards?  Radio shows?  This is a lousy idea for multiple reasons.

Answer (score -5):

I think the new tags you suggest for [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) are a good idea.

Sci-Fi/Fantasy users tend to specialize in either TV and movies or in literature (though some have a vast knowledge of both).  Therefore it would allow the users who specialize in one or the other to sort by those tags.

As far as removing the old [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) or the [media tags](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/should-we-do-away-with-the-media-tags-books-novel-tv-movies-etc), I'm not sure yet.  I could go either way.