# Should movie-identification be a synonym of story-identification?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, story-identification

I was looking through the tags on here a d noticed that, as far as I found, there are three identification tags: [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), [character-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-identification), and [movie-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-identification).  I got to looking and it doesn't seem, to me, that there's any difference between the story and movie tag.  Heck, 3 of the 9 questions tagged with the movie tag also have the story tag.

**Should the movie tag be a synonym for story-identification?**

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) handily covers the territory of [movie-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-identification), so the latter should just be a synonym for the former.

Comment: What movie identification tag;-)

Comment: Darn, I wanted at least 1 upvote before pushing the button.

Comment: @Pearsonartphoto You shouldn't have merged, it would have been better to edit manually to add the [tag:movie] tag.

Answer (score 1):

A while ago, I [proposed](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/630/rename-the-story-identification-tag) splitting [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) into [identify-this-story](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-story) and [identify-this-movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-movie). The response was slightly negative, so I guess we're keeping [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification), which means [movie-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie-identification) should be edited into [story-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/story-identification) + [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie).

[character-identification](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-identification) is a bit different, I think it should stay different.

Comment: I think I'm missing something, how do you edit [tag:movie-identification] -> [tag:story-identification] + [tag:movie]?  Are you saying we manually retag all those [tag:movie-identification] questions?

Comment: @Keen Yes, we could have edited all 9 of them.

Comment: I see, just making sure you weren't referring to some tag manipulation magic that I didn't know of.