# Remove the tv-series tag

Tags: discussion, tags

We have [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) and [tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series) (and [series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series)).  I suppose there's a small possibility that someone might want to distinguish between a one-off TV program and a series, but I don't see any value in separating those cases in tags.

I personally don't like any of the media tags - but [earlier discussion](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/293/should-we-do-away-with-the-media-tags-books-novel-tv-movies-etc) isn't really clear about their fate (and I've seen them - even [series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) - used by mods, which makes me wary about editing them away).  All the positive score answers say that most should only be used when the question is focused on the medium; one suggests leaving some (including [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv)).

**For those that weren't around for the original discussion (or if your view has matured), please go take a look at that question too.**

Assuming that [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv) is here to stay, is it ok to edit out all use of [tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series)? Is there anyone that would prefer a [synonym](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/tv/synonyms)?  If so, please vote for it - if it gets created  (only needs a score of 4) then I guess that's the answer here, and I don't need to edit them away.

There's also now [television](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television), which surely is a synonym for TV. It seems like most people prefer a synonym to just editing them away (until the media tag decision is made), so I've suggested these two synonyms, but as yet there are no votes. If you want the synonym, please go vote for it.

Comment: I OK with synonymizing [tag:tv-series] to [tag:tv]. It would follow the precedent of [tag:movies] being a synonym of [tag:movie]

Comment: This would have been way better than one person flooding the page with retagging tv → tv-series http://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/931/sachin-shekhar?tab=activity

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise - he's working to make the site better. You are criticizing. With all due respect, you should ponder whose contribution helps the site more.

Comment: Asking about which tag is preferred before running off and flooding the front page, not really the best way to go about things. @dvk

Comment: @EightDaysofMalaise - switch to "newest" sort order if flooding from edits bothers you - you'll not see those updates. Yay for options!

Comment: It's questions like these which are productive and seek to gather the community's input that help all instead of actively ignoring when someone else is bulldozing their way through everything @dvk

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[television](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/television) is now merged into [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv).

I've made [tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series) a synonym of [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv), but not merged. This way, any new use of [tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series) will be converted into [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv), but existing uses are retained, so we can go back if it turns out to be a mistake.

---

I second synonymizing [tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series) to [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv). I think [series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/series) should be progressively eliminated manually, replaced by the appropriate media ([tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv), [radio](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio), [comics](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comics), …) if a media tag is deemed necessary.

Answer (score 1):

[tv-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv-series) is quite clearly a meta tag and should be removed.

I also, quite strongly, feel that the collection of { [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv), [radio](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/radio), etc,..) should also be removed as they're of little use either.

To put it another way, which is more useful as a method of categorisation for a question about the Watchmen film, tagged:

- [watchmen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchmen) [watchmen-film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchmen-film)
- [watchmen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchmen) [film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film)

If we worked on the basis that the second case was better, and then there was a question asked about, say the Doctor Who film, tagged [doctor-who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who) and [film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film), we'd then have a tag ([film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film)) containing a question about Doctor Who and a question about Watchmen. **What possible use as a method of grouping questions in the context of *Science Fiction & Fantasy* does this have?**

Now if the two questions (Watchmen and Doctor Who) were tagged:

- [watchmen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchmen) [watchmen-film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchmen-film)
- [doctor-who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who) [doctor-who-film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who-film)

Each tag would stand on its own as a way of categorising questions in the context of **Science Fiction & Fantasy**, rather than the medium in which said piece of SF&F was presented.

If someone's a watchmen geek, but only cares about the film, they can look at [watchmen-film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchmen-film). If another person is only interested in the comic, they can look at [watchmen-comic](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchmen-comic). If yet another person just plain loves watchmen, they can look at [watchmen](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/watchmen) for *anything and everything* watchmen related. The first person (the film geek) can't readily look at [film](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/film) without seeing questions about utterly un-related (in the context of **Science Fiction & Fantasy**) topics.

Comment: Whether there should be media tags or not is covered in http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/293/should-we-do-away-with-the-media-tags-books-novel-tv-movies-etc - please answer/vote in there (I agree, FWIW).

Comment: What is [tag:tv-series] if not a media tag? Or, even worse, a sub-media-tag (argh, my eyes!) =) Perhaps I could've made my answer clearer by using [tag:tv-series] instead of [tag:film], if I get a chance I'll tweak my answer later to do so =)

Comment: I don't think there is value in tagging a question with both watchmen and watchmen-film ... a big fan can follow watchmen-* for everything related to Watchmen, so it could be sufficient just to use watchmen-film. Aside from that, I agree with your larger point about removing tags like film.

Comment: It's clearly a media tag, which is why this is really an answer to the "should there be media tags" meta post. This post is specifically about whether [tag:tv-series] can be removed, given that [tag:tv] exists.