# Should we distinguish the media more clearly?

Tags: discussion, tags

Inspired by the comments on [this](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/36857/13418) answer to a [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) question.

This is mainly regarding Game of Throne but i Think it may concern other universes.

When people ask questions about the series, the answers (mine as well) are often based on the book. It's normal, because there are a lot more details in the books that make us readers understand what them watchers-only cannot. But maybe they wanted a series-based answer ?

So, there are two different tags, [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) and [a-song-of-ice-and-fire](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/a-song-of-ice-and-fire). Is this the way it is intended to be ? It seems to me more logical if there was only one tag (i.e. a-song-of-ice-and-fire which game-of-throne would be a synonym of) and the media tags (see [this meta question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/293/13418)) would precise if the question concerns the books or the tv show.

**The question here is : should we specify the media using different tags per universe or should we use one tag per universe and specify the media with the proper tag ?**

Comment: FWIW, I have a hard time justifying the use of [tag:a-song-of-ice-and-fire] for TV stuff since that name has never been used for the TV show.  It's only used when referring to the source book series.

Comment: It doesn't really seem like a true consensus was reached on the other question, but the issue/subject seems to be pretty much the same.