# Novel and novels tags

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

I was just going over the list of tags, and noticed that there are both 'novel' and 'novels' tags.

Is there a way to merge these into one? 'Novels' is more popular.

Possibly related: [Tags: Novel or Book?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62/tags-novel-or-book)

Answer (score 3):

Moderators can merge tags. I've just merged [novels](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novels) into [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel) which [was prefered by 100% of the people on chat at the time](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1581012#1581012).

In general, if there's a community consensus that two tags are synonyms and should be merged, a [moderator](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/about#moderators) will do it (and if we forget or miss it, ping one of us here on meta, or on chat). For a singular/plural pair, it's obvious that they're synonyms.

Moderators cannot mass-delete a tag. Developers can, but if there are only a few instances, they can be removed by hand. Developers can also blacklist a tag, preventing them from being ever added to a question, if necessary.

Comment: I'm not talking about novel and book - I'm talking about novel and novels... and how do you get a 'community consensus'?

Comment: @HorusKol Oh, sorry, I misread your question. Community consensus means we hash it out on meta and there's no serious objection. Failing consensus, moderators will take the final decision if necessary.

Comment: no worries mate :)